# How to use body for GET method in ADF's web activity with x-www-form-urlencoded content?

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, getmethod, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am working on a task, where i need to call an api use GET method and have to pass some data into body. I am mainly using Azure data factory Web activity for same but I am not able to see any section when i can put the data in body.

[image]

As you can see, the content type is x-www-form-urlencoded so i have to pass grant_type inside body in order to get the required output.
Can someone help me if they were able to pass body while GET method in ADF?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you think it should be a GET? The documentation says it should be a POST. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret

Answer (score 1):

In ***Azure Data Factory*** there is no option **body** in the **GET method**, so you can use the **POST method** to pass some data into the **body**.

I reproduced and created a sample ***example*** you can follow this:

[image: Ref1]
[image: Ref2]
[image: Ref3]

**Reference:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbURJiKoBlg&t=213s

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/get